# Creating datetime sequence in 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create a dateime sequence with minute variable time increments in a temp table . The output should look something like when 5 is used

```
2012-12-13 04:20:00.000
2012-12-13 04:25:00.000
2012-12-13 04:30:00.000
2012-12-13 04:35:00.000
2012-12-13 04:40:00.000
2012-12-13 04:50:00.000
```

Can this be done?

Comment: do you also need to setup the start and end time?

Comment: Yes, I will need a start and end time

Comment: Do you need variable intervals?  Your example has 5 minute intervals at first, but ends with a 10 minute interval.  That makes for a somewhat more intricate CTE or join with a number table.

Comment: No, 5 (or other) minutes through, it will roll over midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH DateTimeSequence
AS
(
  SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2012-12-13 04:20:00', 120) AS [datetime]    -- Start Date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(mi, 5, [datetime])
  FROM   DateTimeSequence
  WHERE  DATEADD(mi, 5, [datetime]) <= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-12-13 04:50:00', 120)      -- End Date
)
SELECT [datetime]
FROM   DateTimeSequence
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12474)

Comment: `option ( MaxRecursion 0 )`, or a more suitable value, may be needed to handle long sequences.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a sequence table - every database should have one because they are so useful generating datetime sequences quickly and easily.

```
CREATE TABLE Sequence
(Number int PRIMARY KEY)
```

Now fill this table with the integers from 0 to 1,000,000 - don't worry, you only need to do this once.

You can then generate datetime sequences as long as you like (well up to 1,000,001) with a variation of

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, Number * @stepsize, @StartDateTime)
FROM Sequence
WHERE Number<@NumberRequired
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0514d/6)

This will generally be faster than using CTE and will be almost as fast as retrieving the info direct from a table. In fact, you may consider not using a temporary table but building a SP (or table valued function) with this at the guts as it will be roughly the same speed and a lot more flexible.